# How to pass a input field in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to pass an input field via a search box I can see in console the value gets updated but it's not passing the correct value. Background I am building a free fuel price watch for my community. Had coded values work via when passed

```
const [data, loading] = useAsyncRequest(10, 4172);
```

my code

AppAsync file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PriceTable from "./tables/PriceTable";
import { useAsyncRequest } from "./hooks";


const AppAsync = () => {
  var suburb = 4172;
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(null);

  const [postCode, setPostCode] = useState(suburb);


  const submitValue = () => {
    const frmdetails = {
      'PostCode': postCode
    }
    suburb = frmdetails.PostCode;
    return suburb;
  }

  console.log(submitValue());
  const [data, loading] = useAsyncRequest(10, submitValue());

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const formattedPrice = data.map((obj, i) => {
        return {
          siteId: i,
          fuelName: obj.fuelName,
          price: obj.price,
          address: obj.address,
          retailer: obj.retailer
        };
      });
      setPrice(formattedPrice);
    }
  }, [data]);


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Latest Fuel Price</h1>

      <hr />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code" onChange={e => setPostCode(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={submitValue}>Submit</button>
      <div className="row">
        {loading || !price ? (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        ) : (
            <div className="seven columns">
              <h2>Fuel Price in your Area</h2>
              <PriceTable
                searches={price}
              />
            </div>
          )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

export default AppAsync;

File useAsyncRequest

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useAsyncRequest = (amount, postCode) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Origin', 'https://localhost:3000');
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://localhost:44396/api/Search?postCode=${postCode}`
        );
        const json = await response.json();

        setData(json.searches, setLoading(false));
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn("Something went wrong fetching the API...", err);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    if (amount) {
      fetchData(amount);
    }
  }, [amount]);

  return [data, loading];
};

export default useAsyncRequest;
```

I am new to react if anyone can point out what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In useAsyncRequest you only trigger the useEffect when amount changes, you need to do it when postCode changes as well.

```
useEffect(()=>{...}, [amount, postCode]);
```

Here is an example with mocked data for the api call:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useAsyncRequest = (amount, postCode) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(() => resolve({
            json: () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve({searches: [
              {
                siteId: postCode,
                fuelName: 'blabla',
                price: amount,
                address: postCode,
                retailer: postCode
              }
            ]}))
          }), 1000);
        });
        const json = await response.json();

        setData(json.searches, setLoading(false));
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn("Something went wrong fetching the API...", err);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    if (amount) {
      fetchData(amount);
    }
  }, [amount, postCode]);

  return [data, loading];
};

export default function App() {
  var suburb = 4172;
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(null);

  const [postCode, setPostCode] = useState(suburb);


  const submitValue = () => {
    const frmdetails = {
      'PostCode': postCode
    }
    suburb = frmdetails.PostCode;
    return suburb;
  }

  console.log(submitValue());
  const [data, loading] = useAsyncRequest(10, submitValue());

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const formattedPrice = data.map((obj, i) => {
        return {
          siteId: i,
          fuelName: obj.fuelName,
          price: obj.price,
          address: obj.address,
          retailer: obj.retailer
        };
      });
      setPrice(formattedPrice);
    }
  }, [data]);


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Latest Fuel Price</h1>

      <hr />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code" onChange={e => setPostCode(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={submitValue}>Submit</button>
      <div className="row">
        {loading || !price ? (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        ) : (
            <div className="seven columns">
              <h2>Fuel Price in your Area</h2>
              {JSON.stringify(price)}
            </div>
          )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```